# rxjava interval function when observeon main thread will throw a error

Tags: rx-java

here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFT3e.png)

Answer (score -1):

What error? `MissingBackpressureException`? `Observable.interval` does not support backpressure and `observeOn` requires it. If you add `.doOnBackpressureXXX()` after the `interval` you will stop getting that error.

Comment: Just an error.It should be a MissingBackpressureException,because when the interval is more length like 10 milliseconds,everything is OK.